# Write href with jQuery at domain level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not sure if the title makes sense or not.

But what I'm doing is looking for an anchor inside a div with the class of banner.  Then trying to write the href as www.domain.com/catno.prd.

However, because what I've build is sat on www.domain.com/foo/bar/  it's returning with  www.domain.com/foo/bar/catno.prd

How can I remove /foo/bar/ so the link returns only on the domain?

Here's what I have

```
$('.banner a').attr('href', function() {
return $sd(this).attr('catno') + '.prd'
});
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a leading `/`:

```
$('.banner a').attr('href', function() {
    return '/' + $sd(this).attr('catno') + '.prd'
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  Can't accept for another 10 minutes but will when I can!  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

@RGraham is correct but [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) has been depreciated use `prop`

```
$('.banner a').prop('href', function() {
    return '/' + $sd(this).prop('catno') + '.prd'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I'm not sure prop will work as we're working with a version of jQuery before 1.6.  I think this is when prop was brought in.  Is this right?  Thanks for your comment!

Comment: `The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.`